# Why does Queue always call 2 times in same one Job?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

I am using Laravel 5.2 framework, I use command to push jobs in to queue (I am using database). I check many times, always queue call 2 time in one job, in 1-2 second different.

```
[2016-03-24 18:12:07] Processed: Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call
[2016-03-24 18:12:09] Processed: Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call
```

my config queue listener is same in Laravel 5.2 doc:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 -daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

Please tell me what did I do wrong here?

Thanks for helping!